# url_for doesn't respect default_url_options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

I would like to get the url using `url_for` with host set in `development.rb`. But instead of this, I get `www.example.com` which isn't set anywhere in directory with application.

```
Connecting to database specified by database.yml
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 COMMAND      database=admin command={:ismaster=>1} (0.5023ms)
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.13)
[1] pry(main)> ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options
=> {:host=>"asd:3000"}
[2] pry(main)> app.posts_url
=> "http://www.example.com/posts"
[3] pry(main)>
```

Does anyone know why and where it come from?

Comment: can you describe your `database.yml` here

Answer (score 1):

I believe that is just how rails outputs the data from the console.  I tested it out myself and in console i get the same thing:

```
[1] pry(main)> app.projects_url
=> "http://www.example.com/projects"
```

And in my `development.rb` file, i specify my host as something else..

**However**, in my application, all routes resolve to the correct place.

Answer (score 0):

You set the options under ActionMailer, so it does not work under console context.

example.com is just Rails filling in the blanks when it is not available.

If you want to get url in development.rb, which is the same as console context, add this on top of development.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = "asd:3000"
```